# Started to learning blockchain from free code camp. Showing this error while compiling

Tags: solidity, blockchain, python, py-solc-x

```py
import json
from solcx import compile_standard, install_solc

with open("./SimpleStorage.sol", "r") as file:
    simple_storage_file = file.read()

print("Installing...")

install_solc('0.6.0')
compiled_sol = compile_standard(
    {
        "language": "Solidity",
        "sources": {"SimpleStorage.sol": {"content": simple_storage_file}},
        "settings": {
            "outputSelection": {
                "*": {
                    "*": ["abi", "metadata", "evm.bytecode", "evm.bytecode.sourceMap"]
                }
            }
        },
    },
    solc_version="v0.6.0",
)

with open("compiled_code.json", "w") as file:
    json.dump(compiled_sol, file)
```

Error message:

```
INFO: Could not find files for the given pattern(s).
Installing...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\mukhe\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\solcx\install.py", line 633, in _validate_installation
    installed_version = wrapper._get_solc_version(binary_path)
  File "C:\Users\mukhe\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\solcx\wrapper.py", line 17, in _get_solc_version    stdout_data = subprocess.check_output([str(solc_binary), "--version"], encoding="utf8")
  File "C:\Users\mukhe\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\subprocess.py", line 420, in check_output
    return run(*popenargs, stdout=PIPE, timeout=timeout, check=True,
  File "C:\Users\mukhe\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\subprocess.py", line 524, in run
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, process.args,
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['C:\\Users\\mukhe\\.solcx\\solc-v0.6.0\\solc.exe', '--version']' returned non-zero exit 
status 3221225595.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\mukhe\solidity\web3_py_simple_storage\deploy.py", line 14, in <module>
    install_solc("v0.6.0")
  File "C:\Users\mukhe\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\solcx\install.py", line 466, in install_solc    
    raise exc
  File "C:\Users\mukhe\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\solcx\install.py", line 459, in install_solc    
    _validate_installation(version, solcx_binary_path)
  File "C:\Users\mukhe\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\solcx\install.py", line 636, in _validate_installation
    raise SolcInstallationError(
solcx.exceptions.SolcInstallationError: Downloaded binary would not execute, or returned unexpected output.
```

Answer (score 0):

I have deployed a solidity code on blockchain too, exactly like you. I think this example can help you.

https://github.com/amiralisahraei/Deploy_smart_contract_on_Rinkeby